# Javascript, all possible options how to (re)create/modify an immutable store (Redux)

Tags: javascript, redux, store, immutability

could someone please help me with all the possible options(or at least the most) on how to modify a store in Redux?

example: Object.assign(), (...spread operator) etc.

I need it to make my personal cheat sheet and maybe others could also find it here for inspiration, if it gets answered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's pretty much two broad ways to do it. One you've already covered which is making a shallow copy of the old state and then changing values within the new object, and the second way is making a deep copy and changing values within the new object.

There are many different ways to go about doing each of these methods, like importing another library to give you a deepClone method or making your own.

The way you'd decide on which is better for your use case is to determine whether or not passing references between shallow copies will break your program or not.